# complex regex for JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

Need to capture below value from string in JMeter

```
<input id="__TriDocumentName" type="hidden" 
value="C%3A%5CWindows%5CTEMP%2Fdocuments%5CBIRTDOCtDY1z2sxwRM6nzf2s7UGO0S%5C20170913_061108_464%5CBalance+Sheet+Report28082017.rptdocument"/>
```

Value to be capture: 20170913_061108_464

what will be the regex for this?

Notice here `BIRTDOCtDY1z2sxwRM6nzf2s7UGO0S` value is also dynamic.

Comment: <input id="__TriDocumentName" type="hidden" value="C%3A%5CWindows%5CTEMP%2Fdocuments%5CBIRTDOCtDY1z2sxwRM6nzf2s7UGO0S%5C20170913_061108_464%5CBalance+Sheet+Report28082017.rptdocument"/>   this is the complete string

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the sampler from which you want to extract dynamic value and add>Post Processors> Regular Expression Extractor.
2. “Apply to” checkbox : Useful in case if sample has child samples that request for embedded resources. This parameter defines will be regular expression be applied to either only main sample results or to the embedded resources too. You can choose according to your requirement
3. “Response field to check” check-box.This parameter defines to which field regular expression should be applied.
4. In regular expression field: **You have to find the left boundary and right boundary of the value to extract for e.g. this is my response "something date:"20170913_061108_464" some value", then my regex will be [date:"(.+?)"] where (date:") is the right boundary and (") is the left boundary**.
5. Template. The template used to create a string from the matches found. This is an arbitrary string with special elements to refer to groups within the regular expression. The syntax to refer to a group is: '$1$' to refer to group 1, '$2$' to refer to group 2, etc. $0$ refers to whatever the entire expression matches. So, if you have in response word “economics” and search for regular expression “(ec)(onomics)” and apply template $2$$1$ than in output variable you will receive “onomicsec”.
6. Match ¹. If there is several character sequences, allows specifying, which variant exactly should be used. Important note. If you set “Apply to” to “Main sample and sub-samples” and specify “Match ¹” = 3, than JMeter will select matching sequence from the 2nd sub-sample because 1st will be main sample. If zero is specified, JMeter will choose a match at random. If you specify negative number, e.g. “-2”
7. To invoke extracted value use the reference name followed by $ sign.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expression Extractor with date pattern after %5C and until next %:

```
Regular Expression : %5C([0-9\_]+)%

Template: $1$

Match No: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expression Extractor with below pattern

> Regular Expression : [A-Z]+%5C([0-9_]+)%5
>
> Template :$1$
>
> Match No : 1

Comment: Is it too similar to my answer?

Comment: your regex will not discard dynamic value!!

Answer (score 0):

The code below is working.

```
<input id="__TriDocumentName" type="hidden" value="C%3A%5CWindows%5CTEMP%2Fdocuments%5C.*?%5C(.*?)%5CBalance\+Sheet\+Report28082017.rptdocument"
```